# Save image from UIWebView to camera roll with gesture

Tags: ios, image, uiwebview, save

Hi I am a little stuck saving an image, I have constructed a gesture and followed a tutorial but am a little stuck with the final part of actually saving the image.
Any help would be gratefully appreciated 
Here is the tutorial source

http://bees4honey.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-save-an-image-from-uiwebview/

Thanks in advance

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap:)];
doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
[self.myWebView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];


}

-(void) doubleTap :(UITapGestureRecognizer*) sender {
int scrollPositionY = [[self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.pageYOffset"] intValue];
int scrollPositionX = [[self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.pageXOffset"] intValue];

int displayWidth = [[self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.outerWidth"] intValue];
CGFloat scale = myWebView.frame.size.width / displayWidth;

CGPoint pt = [sender locationInView:self.myWebView];
pt.x *= scale;
pt.y *= scale;
pt.x += scrollPositionX;
pt.y += scrollPositionY;

NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).tagName", pt.x, pt.y];
NSString * tagName = [self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];

NSString *imgURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).src", startPoint.x, startPoint.y];
NSString *urlToSave = [self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:imgURL];


/// Stuck at this point to actually get the file
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToSave];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, <#id completionTarget#>, <#SEL completionSelector#>, <#void *contextInfo#>)
```

You can pass nil to all the three parameters. so you can call

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, That is very close to what I was looking for but I got the error Sending NSString strong to parameter of type NSURL  and when I tried the gesture I got this in the debug __NSCFString isFileURL, If you have another idea I'd love to try it or maybe I have made a mistake earlier , thanks again

Comment: Try this now. I forgot to make a url with the string you have. This should work. I made edits to the above answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the most direct and it just works solution that I have found